# Can we pass string to json encode method in php

Tags: php

I always noticed that json_encode method gets array as arguments. My question is can we use String instead of array  as arguments for the method

```
json_encode($array);
```

Updated

Hi please check the following code. I convert the string in to jason

```
 $jason = '<h3 style="font-size:15px;">';
    foreach($employee as $key=> $value){
        $jason .= '<table><tbody>';
        $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:400px;padding:5px;padding:10px;"></td><td style="width:300px;padding:5px;"><img style="width:132px; height:175px;" src="'.$image_folder.$value->prfil_img .'" /></td></tr>';
    //$retval .= '<a href="'. $store_url . 'product_info.php?products_id=' . $product_id . '"><img src="' . $image_folder . $product_image . '" /></a><br />';

         $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'Name:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->first_name.'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value->last_name.'</td></tr>';
         $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'Email:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->email;'</td></tr>';
         $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'Tel Ext:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->extension;'</td></tr>';
         $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'Account:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->account;'</td></tr>';
         $jason .= '</table></tbody>';
        // echo '</br>';echo '</br>';

   }
        $jason .= '</h3>';

   echo json_encode($jason);
```

But then I get following out put

[image]

But if I don't use jason encode I get the results clearly. (without having broken syntax of html element). So anybody has any idea on this? Where I have done the mistake?

As I use ajax in wordpress , I need to use jason encoded data.

Please not that when I apply jason encode to following I get following out put

```
$jason = '<tr><td style="width:90%;font-size:14px;">';
$jason .= 'val 2';
echo json_encode($jason) ;
```

Out put is "val 2"
Therefore, I think jason format data.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can

form http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

"The value being encoded. Can be any type except a resource."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) shows that `mixed value` can be used as input.

Answer (score 3):

If you note in the PHP manual for `json_encode()` it says this:

> Note:
>
> Like the reference JSON encoder, json_encode() will generate JSON that
>   is a simple value (that is, neither an object nor an array) if given a
>   string, integer, float or boolean as an input value. While most
>   decoders will accept these values as valid JSON, some may not, as the
>   specification is ambiguous on this point.

So, you can pass a string value and it will encode it, just don't expect that value to be able to be universally decoded.  Depending on your usage, you might be better off placing it in an array wrapper.

Also, this function doesn't just take arrays, it will also properly encode objects (or other simple values as noted).

Comment: +1, for `universally read`. Most of the time it's placed directly in javascript code or read from `$.JSON`, but it's not a surprise if it doesn't read a custom class or object.

Comment: thanks this is more clear answer, I noticed lot of time ,array is used in coding.

Comment: I've seen it most used in ajax, as for what kind of data jQuery or whatever framework you might be using, it might require the `[]` wrapper. That said, if you look at OrangePill's answer, that also is a common way of including json encoded information. If you do decide to include it like that, there's no problem then. `var a = "hello world";`

Comment: Yes @OrangePill gives a good example of how this "feature" may be used when outputting PHP variable data directly into a script block for variable assignment in javascript.

Comment: Generally that's unwanted though, mainly because then either you have Javascript inline with html (instead of including which is better), or you have non-static `.js` files which can't be cached.

Answer (score 2):

Well it says `mixed`, I'm pretty sure a string works fine too.

And look! [It does!](http://codepad.org/vGR4Tfw4)

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
  $a = '"Hello World"';

  echo json_encode ($a);

  // outputs "\"Hello World\""   with the quotes
```

Note this will properly escape characters withing the string so you could say

```
  <script>
      var a = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
  </script>
```

Without having two worry about performing the escaping yourself.